# How can we specify Jar/Libraries version from Airflow Dag code to a Databricks Job using the major/minor versions created by Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, airflow, azure-databricks, continuous-deployment, cicd

We are trying to specify the jar versions to be used by the Databricks job depending on the image version created by the Azure Pipeline on a specific git branch. We want to avoid manual changes in the Airflow Dag code to specify jar versions and looking for a solution which does this automatically without any changes to Dag code.

Eg :
Jar/Lib name : share-05.01.00.1234.jar

This jar/lib versions has to be passed to the Databricks job while running the job on Databricks through airflow. Here the version "05.01.00.1234" is generated by the Azure Pipeline on the git repo and this version has to be specified in the jar name so that we know what version of the software we are running.

We are looking for a solution where the deployment pipelines can take care of this version stuff in the Airflow Dag code.

We tired with wildcards(*) but Databricks does not support wildcards(*) in jar version.